# Cannot activate Windows 7 on a stickerless Lenovo

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Lenovo T520 laptop that came with Windows 7 Professional.

The laptop does not have a Windows license sticker, but it came with legal system preinstalled. I was able to retrieve the Product Key with NirSoft ProduKey.

I am sure that the key is correct, because I have used it before doing system recovery.

This time I wanted to make a clean reinstall though. After reinstalling, the Product Key is not accepted by Windows. The error message that I receive says:

> A problem occured when Windows tried to activate. Error Code 0xC004E003

What should I do to activate Windows with this product key?

Comment: A google search found this, which may be useful: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_install/activation-error-code-0xc004e003-product-key/09f326fe-fbcd-4a95-b08a-32a0c4e8d7aa?auth=1

Comment: Alzo this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931276

Comment: The key installed by Lenovo is a Volume License Key and will not work with regular Windows Installation media. If your recovery partition is gone or not working you will need to order a recovery disc set from Lenovo.

Comment: Thanks Moab, your solution was useful. It turned out that there actually was a sticker with the license key. The sticker was located behind the battery.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that there actually was a sticker with the license key. The sticker was located behind the battery.